# How to mount Airflow DAGs via Git?

Tags: airflow

Found that in airflow.cfg there is possibility to 'Mount DAGs via Git':

```
# Git credentials and repository for DAGs mounted via Git (mutually exclusive with volume claim)
git_repo = https://username@bitbucket.org/repo.git
git_branch = master
git_subpath =
# Use git_user and git_password for user authentication or git_ssh_key_secret_name and git_ssh_key_secret_key
# for SSH authentication
git_user = username
git_password = pass
git_sync_root = /git
git_sync_dest = repo
# Mount point of the volume if git-sync is being used.
# i.e. /home/user/airflow/dags
git_dags_folder_mount_point = /home/user/airflow/dags
```

Was unable to find any documentation on this.

Do I understand it correctly, that I am able to deploy my DAGs to Airflow production server using Git repo by just pushing to the branch specified?

Couldn't get that operating, would appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Are you using the KubernetesExecutor? These settings are under the `[kubernetes]` header and are intended to be used in that context. https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L586

Comment: No, I wasn't. That must be the answer, why it didn't work. Will try with k8s, thanks!